# Idiomatic way to do multiple queries in golang in one transaction

Tags: go

I'm currently struggling (my 2nd day) to find the best way to do multiple queries and was wondering if you know a solution.

I have an open *sql.DB Connection, named **myDb** and use the *go-sql-driver*

```
func TruncateGalleryImport() error {

    s := make([]string, 0)

    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE add_map")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_permission")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_watch")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_user_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_watch")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE private_map")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE attachment")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE attachment_data")

    for _, q := range s {
        _, err := myDb.Exec(q)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Is it possible to commit all the above queries together using only one transaction?

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a Transaction, like this (see the comments in the code):

```
func TruncateGalleryImport() error {
    s := make([]string, 0)

    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE add_map")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_permission")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE album_watch")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_user_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_view")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE media_watch")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE private_map")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE attachment")
    s = append(s, "TRUNCATE TABLE attachment_data")

    // Get new Transaction. See http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Begin
    txn, err := myDb.Begin()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        // Rollback the transaction after the function returns.
        // If the transaction was already commited, this will do nothing.
        _ = txn.Rollback()
    }()

    for _, q := range s {
        // Execute the query in the transaction.
        _, err := txn.Exec(q)

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    // Commit the transaction.
    return txn.Commit()
}
```

Comment: Beware: it only work for database engines whose truncate statement is transactional. For a number of them (Oracle, MySQL), it is not. Truncate table is commonly implemented as a DDL operation, rather than a DML.

Comment: Great help! Thanks for including the defer statement!!

Comment: To be clear, some MySQL engines (`InnoDB`) do support transactions, whereas others (`MyISAM`) do not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a wrapped function to do the commit/rollback logic, possibly even expand the error handling using string matching.

```
// RDBTransaction is a function which abstracts a sql transaction
// into a function with an isolation level (isolvl) parameter.
// the following integers represent the available isolation levels (isolvl)
//  1: SERIALIZABLE
//  2: REPEATABLE READ
//  3: READ COMMITTED
//  4: READ UNCOMMITTED
func RDBTransaction(db *sql.DB, isolvl int, fn func(*sql.Tx) error) (err error) {
    var tx *sql.Tx
    tx, err = db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // transaction isolation level setting
    switch isolvl {
    case 1:
        _, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level serializable`)
    case 2:
        _, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level repeatable read`)
    case 3:
        _, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level read committed`)
    case 4:
        _, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level read uncommitted`)
    default:
        _, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level serializable`)
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // catch all, commit/rollback
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return
        }
        err = tx.Commit()
    }()

    // run transaction
    err = fn(tx)

    return err
}
```